# Byte array (byte string) data structure with persistent, pure interface

Tags: data-structures, idris, bytestring

I'm looking for a data structure that stores bytes, allows constant-time pure indexing, and presents a pure, persistent interface for updating. Basically, I'm looking for Idris's equivalent of Haskell (strict) [bytestrings](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring).

[`Data.ByteArray`](https://github.com/ziman/idris-bytes/blob/master/Data/ByteArray.idr) provides a mutable byte array that is accessible from `IO` only; and it builds [`Data.Bytes`](https://github.com/ziman/idris-bytes/blob/master/Data/Bytes.idr) on top of that which at first glance seems promising; however, it doesn't seem to have an indexing operation, and updating seems to only be possible by splitting and re-concatenating.